# using fragments in android 2.2 dynamically

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-support-library

Okay am a newbie in developing for android and have searched all places for an example on using fragments dynamically in android 2.2, so far i have learnt using Support libraries and my code seems okay it compiles installs on the emulator but crashes when launched and i can't seem to know why. If anyone would show me how for example to create a fragment with a button that displays another with a text view when clicked i would really be glad. Examples would really help. Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: First of all, It is much preferable if you upload your codes too.
Second of all,  I don't think your android support any codes for android 2.2. Codes to control fragments have changed since Ice Cream Sandwich I guess ( don't remember the API level). So, try for something like Ice Cream Sandwich or Jelly Bean, if you can. There are tons of great tutorials out there.

Comment: First of all, are you following any tutorial? If not, try tutorials from Udactiy (www.udacity.com)

Comment: it reads call requires API level 11 current is 8

Comment: I dont think anybody is using API 11 or 8 anymore. Move up. Target for API level 18 - 21.